# Required to call `systemd-resolve` each time I connect to VPN

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

Whenever I connect to a VPN using OpenVPN I have to run the following command or I cannot access some websites:

`sudo systemd-resolve --set-dns=1.1.1.1 --interface=wlp111s0`

Is there a way to permanently fix this so that I don't have to run the command every time I connect to the VPN?

In my /etc/openvpn/client.conf I have the following `dhcp-option` set, where "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" are specific DNS servers:

```
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
```

In my attempts to fix this I have tried adding 1.1.1.1 and corresponding 2606:4700:4700::1111 to my IPv4 and IPv6 network settings (i.e. through the GUI).

I have tried adding them as name servers in /etc/resolv.conf

Out of desperation I have also added it to my /etc/network/interfaces file using this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface wlp111s0 inet dhcp
  dns-nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

So far none of them have worked.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.06

Does anyone know why I have to manually set the DNS each time?
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the DNS servers that you refer to, but rather, use the DNS servers provided by your VPN... else you get what is known as a DNS leak. See https://dnsleak.com and https://dnsleaktest.com to confirm this.

Comment: @heynnema Good information, thanks!